# What does it mean to have "readability" in a programming language?

Tags: typescript

I just watched [Clement's video on TypeScript](https://youtu.be/eCZhz0JCVx0?t=279) and he mentions  "your code has to go through Readability Review with someone who ***has*** readability".

What does "has readability" mean? How does a person "have" readability?

A few seconds later he even says "Guess who has readability?" (Points to himself) "This Guy".

Would like some perspective, thanks!

Comment: I assume he uses it as shorthand for "someone who is allowed to do readability reviews".

Comment: i.e. someone who know what the best practices are. In other words, it's broken english, the very opposite of readability :')

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about understanding an English sentence, not about programming.

Comment: I think he means "the ability to write readable code". It wouldn't mean anything to take a readability review from someone who is not capable of writing readable code in the first place. "your code has to go through Readability Review with someone who is themselves capable of writing readable code".

Comment: @DaveCousineau: The phrase "to have X" is a contracted form of "to have (the capability to do) X" that is at least common in Role-Playing or Gaming circles. I'm guessing it comes from RPGs, where you, if your character is good at X, you would write down X on your character sheet, and it is then only a small step to saying things like "I have X (on my sheet)" or simply "I have X". The accepted answer by a person working in the same team confirms that "have readability" means "have the power to conduct a Readability Review". Being capable of writing readable code may be a pre-requisite of that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag nice example. Sure, in the context of the video, readability in a language is an ability you unlock after many a code change in said language. Writing readable code should be a prerequisite, not a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is off topic for StackOverflow, but as someone who also has TypeScript readability, let me explain.

All code changes being checked in need to be reviewed. No exceptions (well, there are, but it's not relevant).

Code changes that touch Google languages (including TypeScript) require extra attention for style guidelines, best practices, etc. Such code changes will need a review from someone who has "readability" in that language.

There is a process that grants you incremental readability, the most obvious way to gain readability in a language is to write lots of code in it.

Full disclosure: I work at Google.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it - there's an internal process for incremental readability. 

Do you have suggestions for a better forum to ask this question at? StackOverflow does have "readability" and "code-readability" tags, and this question is very much about me starting to learn about the topic in depth and get my code up to "Readability" standards.

Comment: @echorashmi those tags don't exist, and should not. I've removed them. I'm not quite sure what the right forum is. If the person in the YouTube video left you links to contact them, I suppose that'd be fine. Otherwise look them up on GitHub and reach out there.